# SVG image not aligning to equivalent of 'object-fit' in 100vh viewport

Tags: html, css, image, svg, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to get an SVG image to be the equivalent of `object-fit` inside an 100vh full screen container.  From what I can gather I need to use the `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` attribute and set `width="100%" height="100%"`

I can't seem to get it work though? When I play around with it, there is either a chunk of whitespace showing at the bottom of the container, or when the image does fill the viewport the viewport then becomes a lot bigger than 100vh?

Just to note I can't use the CSS background-image property because it is part of a wider SVG / Javascript animation I'm building.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/YJYrEa

Does anyone know what is going wrong here and what the solution would be?

Thanks in advance for any help / ideas.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#section-1, .background-clipped {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-1">
<div class="background-clipped background-clipped-1">
    <svg id="home-image-1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.postimg.cc/9XdQKYF1/dimon-blr-309444-unsplash.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </svg>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Seems to me that if this isn't a square image then your viewbox is wrong. May not be related though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple sizing mechanisms at work; one for the `<svg>` element, one for the `<image>` element.

The one you set for the `<svg>` element is not really helpfull. The `viewBox` attribute fits a coordinate system of 100 by 100 user units inside the container. This coordinate system is then the viewport for sizing the `<image>` with an implicit `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"`. If you find that confusing: yes, that is the problem.

Instead, just size the `<svg>` element to fill the container. Remove the `viewBox`, set `width` and `height` to 100%. Without a `viewBox`, `preserveAspectRatio` also has no effect on the `<svg>` element.

Now, only the sizing mechanism for your image (fit the nimage into the 100% width and height of the viewport, as `preserveAspectRatio` describes), takes effect and works as you want it to.

**General note**: a JPG, as used in your `<image>`, has an inherent aspect ratio. Therefore `preserveAspectRatio` will always have an effect. A `<svg>` element has not. Only a `viewBox` has one. and is what the attribute works on.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#section-1, .background-clipped {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-1">
<div class="background-clipped background-clipped-1">
    <svg id="home-image-1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <image xlink:href="https://i.postimg.cc/9XdQKYF1/dimon-blr-309444-unsplash.jpg"
               x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
    </svg>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: That's a wonderful answer.  I realised just as you answered I'd made a mistake on my code, i'd mistakenly put the preserveAspectRatio attribute on my `<image>` element instead of the `<svg>`.  But that shouldn't affect things hopefully.

Comment: Oh bugger it does affect things. I've put preserveAspectRatio on both which seems to solve the problem though.  Thanks again.

Comment: There is a reason why I didn't set preserveAspectRatio on the `<svg>` element. See edit.